# SVG with embedded bitmap not showing bitmap when using <img> tag in webkit browser

Tags: svg, bitmap, webkit

I am trying to use a SVG with an embedded bitmap as a navigation element. The idea is to make it more mobile friendly. I already have a PNG fallback in place for IE8 and below.

Somehow the embedded bitmap doesn't show in webkit based browsers. SVG without bitmap embedded show just fine.

I can get the background to show in webkit using the "object" tag but then my links don't work, I can't control the width and I run into a documented bug of safari where image is not scaled and sliders appear.

See the page in question here:
http://www.izbornareforma.rs/izbori-2012/
All images are SVG, the four bottom one have embedded bitmap in them.

There are a number of similar question but none have a workable solution.

Suggestions welcome.

G.D.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Webkit. If you keep your current backgrounds **and also** load the same SVGs in an `object` tag you will see that the SVG backgrounds will load correctly with the embedded data. To work around this I would suggest you to create an invisible `div` where you load your SVGs in `object` tags, such as...

```
<div id="svgfix">
  <object ... />
  <object ... />
  <object ... />
  <object ... />
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
#svgfix {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the link to the webkit bugreport for this?

Comment: @ErikDahlström I recall another bug report from around 2011 but this is the same bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170560

Comment: I had missed that also in your answer. Now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Safari (5.1.10 - Snow Leopard, or 8.0.4 - Yosemite) or on Mobile Safari (iOS 8.1). Basically it just doesn't work now, if it ever did... unless I'm missing something in your explanation, but I thought it was pretty straightforward. What I have found is that the bitmap embed works if you use the SVG tag by itself in the HTML, but since the SVG tag can't be styled(?) it's not a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [corresponding Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99677) was fixed and rolled-out with Safari 9.