# svg image using xlink:href not working in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

i have this image using xlink:href

```
file    xxx.svg:

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="103" height="92.75" viewBox="0 0 103 92.75">

<image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://gw.alicdn.com/tps/i4/TB1QygcLFXXXXcmaXXXTQYPHFXX-60-41.png"  width="40" height="28"/>

  <..something else>
```

it works perfectly in chrome only if I open it directly as a url address

but when i reference it in an html

```
<img src="xxx.svg"/>
```

the image is gone.

all the other objects in the svg file are shown except the image tag. neither in mobile chrome.

i tried other webkit browsers, the html referenced svg image works fine in safari.

i tried dataURI, still not shown in chrome. https://gw.alicdn.com/tps/TB1LsQqLFXXXXXYXpXXXXXXXXXX-103-92.svg
[image]
[image]

EDIT： in my browser, if i visit this page in new tab, the image above displayed as a empty circle.

after i click the link, the browser tab jump to the image, image shows correctly.

after i hit browser back, the page return to here this page, the image changed, it is shown.

Comment: A data URI should work if you get it right. Show us what you did for that.

Comment: https://gw.alicdn.com/tps/TB1LsQqLFXXXXXYXpXXXXXXXXXX-103-92.svg

Comment: It works but displays the wrong viewport is that what you're issue is?

Comment: in my browser, there are some circle and stars, no coins at all. click the link shows differently

Comment: Raise a chrome bug on their bug tracker. It works in Firefox.

Comment: Searched for bug (and tried myself and must confirm it behaves odd).
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170560 (with ref to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483215/

Comment: had any solution ?

Comment: no. just quit using xlink. It's a chrome bug

Answer (score 4):

The use of `xlink:herf` has beed deprecated in SVG

so when you open the svg directly it work as the file it self does not contain it

https://css-tricks.com/on-xlinkhref-being-deprecated-in-svg/